# How to NSLog the name of an object in NSArray

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective-C, and I am currently reading *Objective-C: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide to Programming*. I am trying to add some code to a completed example in hopes of learning how to print the name of the objects in an array along with their values. I was able to print the values, but I am stuck on trying to print the name of the objects. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        // create three NSDate objects
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSDate *tomorrow = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0];
        NSDate *yesterday = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:-24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0];

        // create an empty mutable array
        NSMutableArray *dateList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        // add two dates to the array
        [dateList addObject:now];
        [dateList addObject:tomorrow];

        // add yesterday at the beginning of the list
        [dateList insertObject:yesterday atIndex:0];

        // iterate over the array
        for (NSDate *d in dateList) {
             NSLog(@"Here is the date: %@\n\n", d);
             sleep(2);
        }

        // remove yesterday
        [dateList removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Now the first date is: %@\n\n", dateList[0]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What would you like to see?

Comment: Instead of printing "Here is the date: (date)" in the first NSLog statement, I would like to print "The date for yesterday is: (date)", "The date for today is: (date)", and "The date for tomorrow is: (date)". I could not figure out how to print the names of the objects today, tomorrow and yesterday in their respective places.

Comment: @bnkohrn There is no way to get a variable name at runtime because they aren't copied to the binary.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you would want to use a NSMutableDictionary instead of an NSMutableArray which will give you the ability to add an object and a key for each object. Then once you have your Dictionary you can print the key and value with this loop

```
        for (NSString *key in dict) {
            NSLog(@"'%@' = '%@'", key, [dict objectForKey:key]); 
           }
```

Comment: Ah, I knew about the NSDictionary, but I was stumped on trying to figure it out for NSArray. It turns out I was stumped for good reason! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is bit theoretical for me to understand what the actual goal is, so there is some doubled up stuff both there and in my answer, like putting in objects in order into an array, just to pull them out in order again, but here's what you specifically asked for. I think:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOf3Days = [NSMutableArray array];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *tomorrow = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0];
NSDate *yesterday = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:-24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0];


[arrayOf3Days addObject:yesterday];
[arrayOf3Days addObject:now];
[arrayOf3Days addObject:tomorrow];

for (int i = 0; i < arrayOf3Days.count; i++) {

    NSDate *thisDay = [arrayOf3Days objectAtIndex:i];

    if (i == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Yesterday: %@\n\n", thisDay);
    }else if(i == 1){
        NSLog(@"Today: %@\n\n", thisDay);
    }else if(i == 2){
        NSLog(@"Tomorrow: %@\n\n", thisDay);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer because the if statement or switch statement make more sense to me for this application of iterating through the NSArray. This is actually what I was looking for. Thank you!